# lightness algorithm using HSI

Tags: image-processing, colors, computer-vision

Anyone know any algorithm to non-linearly change lightness using HSI model?

I am currently doing something like this.
new intensity = old intensity^(1/4) 
It increases lightness of  dark color more than lightness of bright color.
The problem is that before enhancement, if I have some pixels look like black color because of very low lightness, their lightness increase after enhancement and their actual colors appear which make black area of photo has different colors(eg: grey,blue). I have tried quite a few ways to solve it by lowering new lightness of black spot but I have no luck so far.

Is there anyway to solve it or is there better algorithm? The problem is only with color which appear to be black before enhancement.

Please help. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HSI values of dark pixels are usually degenerate. This is because, for example, a fully saturated maximally-dark blue = black, is identical in appearance to a completely de-saturated (grey) pixel at its darkest = black (this is the reason the 3D space shape usually has a pointed tip at the degenerate/singular colors).

You should not enhance pixels under a certain threshold value, or alternatively, use some weighting function that inhibits enhancement at the very dark values.